# Can't find out which usb port is the one at the front

Tags: linux, usb, power-management

I have 2 fronta usb plugs but I want to know which ones are so I can turn on or suspend the power of one of them.

the motherboard has 4 back usb plugs at the back and two at the front.

ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/

```
1-0:1.0/     1-3.4/       1-3.4.3:1.0/ 1-3.4.4:1.1/ usb2/        
1-3/         1-3.4:1.0/   1-3.4.4/     2-0:1.0/     
1-3:1.0/     1-3.4.3/     1-3.4.4:1.0/ usb1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `sudo dmesg` and then connect a device to the port